# Stop editing / cancel / deselect / whatever you call it TextField on click away in MacOS app

Tags: swift, swiftui

I just have a text field and I want it to stop being "highlighted" or active when I click away, like if the user decides not to use it. Not on send or done. It's an element that you may enter something in and choose not to "send" for a while, so it would be nice if it wouldn't sit there looking active. Is there a SwiftUI way of doing this? I only see UIKit and NS solutions online.

I know this must be so simple, so I'm sorry for that. Have done a lot of looking to no avail, though.

Comment: Use the disabled modifier

Comment: That grays it out, I just want it to return to it's look before it was touched.

Comment: Look into focused for iOS 15 I think you mean that you want it to resign focus or first responder

Comment: show us the code you use and what you have tried already, so we don't keep repeating what you have done.

Comment: @ElliotD what happen when you press tab? It should deselect your field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem it with help extension for UIApplication

```
extension UIApplication {
    func addTapGestureRecognizer() {
        guard let window = windows.first else { return }
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: window, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
        tapGesture.requiresExclusiveTouchType = false
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        tapGesture.delegate = self
        window.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
}

extension UIApplication: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true // set to `false` if you don't want to detect tap during other gestures
    }
}
```

and after you can use it for example:

```
let contentView = ContentView()
            .onAppear(perform: UIApplication.shared.addTapGestureRecognizer)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for SwiftUI App life cycle. This approach relies on AppKit App Delegate

Comment: Why not? I'm used it without AppDelegate:

@main
struct iosApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onAppear(perform: UIApplication.shared.addTapGestureRecognizer)
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

you could use this "textFieldStyle(.plain)" as a base, then add your own borders as desired:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var txt1 = "text1"
    @State var txt2 = "text2"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("test1", text: $txt1).textFieldStyle(.plain)
            TextField("test2", text: $txt2).textFieldStyle(.plain)
        }.frame(width: 444, height: 444)
    }
}
```